# Generalisation of Triangular Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been trying to prove that:

$$\forall n,k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists q \in \mathbb{N},\quad(2n+1)^2 t_k + t_n = t_q$$

Where $t_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is the $n$th triangular number.

I've seen this has a proof in the Journal of Recreational Mathematics, by R. F. Jordan, but I've been unable to find a copy (and unable to prove it myself, obviously).

My attempts haven't got very far - mostly just algebraic manipulation and trying to factorise into something resembling a triangular number in terms of $n$ and $k$. I'm not familiar with many identities related to triangle numbers.

Any tips/a proof would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is actually rather underwhelming: if we multiply everything by $2$, we want to show that for integer $k,n$, there is $q$ so that
$$ (2n+1)^2 k(k+1)+n(n+1) = q(q+1). $$
Expanding the left-hand side gives
$$ 4 k^2 n^2+4 k^2 n+k^2+4 k n^2+4 k n+k+n^2+n, $$
which factorises (no, I don't know how one spots this...) into
$$ (k+n+2kn)(k+n+2kn+1), $$
so $q=k+n+2kn$.

Comment: A possible way to spot the factorization is to try a few values of $k$ and deduce a pattern, not very smart but plausible.

Comment: Argh. I tried a bunch of factorisations but yeah, missed this one. Awesome, thank you for the quick response.

Comment: It does feel like there should be some ingenious proof without words that wraps the whole thing up into one nifty triangle, but I can't say I can spot it, at least at present.

Comment: $4 k^2 n^2+4 k^2 n+k^2+4 k n^2+4 k n+k+n^2+n=(2kn +n+k)^2+ 2 k n+n+k=(2kn+n+k)(2kn+n+k+1)$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(2n+1)^2 t_k+t_n =\frac{(2n+1)^2 k(k+1) +n(n+1)}{2} \\
=\frac{(2n+1)^2k^2+(4n^2+4n+1)k+n(n+1)}{2} \\
=\frac{(2n+1)^2k^2+(\overbrace{2n^2+n}^{(2n+1)n}+\overbrace{2n^2+3n+1}^{(2n+1)(n+1)})k+n(n+1)}{2} \\
=\frac{((2n+1)k+n)((2n+1)k+n+1)}{2} 
\end{eqnarray*}
So $q=(2n+1)k+n$.